# USB flash drive empty folders

Tags: windows, usb

I have a USB drive that holds a lot of folders and documents I took from another computer. The folders are there but the problem is that all of them appear empty.

I tried showing hidden folders and check if those files were hidden. I scanned the drive with an antivirus suite. I tried to change the drive's properties with `attrib -h -s f: *.*`. None of this worked. What else can I do?

Comment: Try attrib -r -a -s -h -i /S /D f:\*.*

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why there might really be no files on the USB stick:

- you didn't have enough permissions to read the files on the other PC
- the files were too large for the USB stick
- you removed the USB stick without ejecting it. The files might be cached for writing but writing has not completed yet. This depends on the operating system and on Settings of that PC.
- the USB stick is buggy. Check it with [h2testw](http://www.heise.de/download/h2testw.html) (but doing this will certainly erase everything!)

Things you still can try

- when using attrib, apply the /S switch to process all subfolders.
- have a look at the USB Stick with [FTK Imager Lite](http://www.accessdata.com/support/product-downloads)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d f:\*.*
```

or

```
attrib -h -r -s f:\*.* /s /d
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Thomas W.'s answer, there's always the possibility that you've somehow marked your files as hidden. If nothing that Thomas said helped, it's worth a try just to press Ctrl+H on your keyboard to see if it's all hidden or not. This most likely isn't the problem, but - again - worth a shot if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your computer and USB Drive have been infected with a Virus.

There are two possibilities

1. Your files are present on the USB Flash Drive, but are not visible in your Windows.Try connecting to a Linux Operating System and check if you can access the files.
2. The virus has deleted the files from your USB Drive. Use a tool like Recuva to recover the files from your USB Flash Drive

I have seen the 2nd possibility with one of my USB Drives and I have successfully recovered the files using Recuva.

You might to want check these links to prevent such virus from infecting your USB/Computer again

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

[Protecting USB flash drive against viruses](https://superuser.com/questions/418438/protecting-usb-flash-drive-against-viruses/690481#690481)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
go to device manager, universal serial bus controllers,
right click usb root hub, properties, power management. 
uncheck 'allow commputer to turn off to save power'
do this for all usb root hubs.

flash drive should work now.
this will drain your laptops power though.

Comment: Can you explain how this relates to the question?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is USB power management? The device can be read by the computer, it just doesn't contain any files visible to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 1.

Check whether files are not in hidden mode.

Click on "Start" --> In search box, type cmd and press "Enter".

"Command Prompt" will be opened.

Here I assume your pen drive letter as G:

Enter this command.

attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:*.*

[You can copy the above command --> Right-click in the Command Prompt and

paste it.]

Note : Don't forget to replace the letter g with your pen drive letter.

Now press "Enter".

Now check for your files in your pen drive.

Good Luck.

Comment: I guess you didn't notice that there already was an answer posted Oct 22 2014 suggesting the same remedy (with just different order of parameters) ?

Comment: well said @zagrimsan, i suggest you to do not give up :)