# USB folder says it's empty and the command prompt says the path to the folder doesn't exist

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I used a camera from a school library and imported the pictures onto my USB. But now my USB says the folder is empty which is weird because even the folder icon shows images of their being files in the folder. I already looked up solutions and one of them suggested using the command prompt but even when I typed in the right command my computer said the path to drive E could not be found. How do I fix this? I have really important files for a group project on there. Also, I am broke so don't sell me stuff XD

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: A very similar problem is vented here, https://superuser.com/q/691629/620011 Your library computer likely put some special permissions, which you don't have on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

@Adrienne Watt - You should share some screenshots so we understand more about the problem. Yet here are few things to start with (I will keep lang as simple as possible).

a) You mentioned - drive isn't found. Are you sure your USB is getting detected. Use different ports of your machine. You can see popups on the systray(where time appears) and info on "usb being detected" etc.

b) Is it really E: drive. Use "My computer" and see what drives are shown. Because you shouldn't see this error unless a drive doesnt exist.

c) A folder can show some images but empty because a hidden file is present in the directory with extension .db that will have some cache data. You can try that in you c: drive or so. Put some pics and movies. Change the view to thumbnail. Delete the items off.. you can still see "images" on the folder. So that is not an indication that something is really there.

d) I do not think the USB circuitry has a problem. In such cases you will get "device not identified" pop up near time applet.

e) I do not think the "flash file system" has corruption. In that case you should get a pop up box that says "Format disk".

Comment: How do I put a photo on here? I doubled checked and the USB is on my E drive.  I unplugged and replugged my usb but it still didn't work. Sometimes when I do that though it shows folders on the usb but still nothing comes up in the folders

Comment: After you copied "data" were you able to see that in some system at a later point? At least once? Or is this the first time you are checking if data is there? If you are sure it is E:drive , go to command prompt and go to some folder where you should have data and not folders again. and type this e:\somefolder> dir /a